# Why isnt my proxy changing when I change it in the textbox? C# .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, proxy, webbrowser-control

I'm currently playing around with proxies, and its working just fine, everything is working perfectly according to plan, except for the small issue that my application doesnt seem to react to the textbox.

As you can see in the code below, im changing the proxy settings in the registry, and it works just fine when I have it like this.

> registry.SetValue("ProxyServer", 201.48.34.200:3128);

But if I change it to this, and input the same IP and port in the textbox itself (proxyIP.Text) it doesnt change the proxy in the registry. any ideas what might be causing this? I tried debugging, but its not showing anything unusual.

> registry.SetValue("ProxyServer", proxyIP.Text);

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ProxyTesting
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RegistryKey registry = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings", true);

            registry.SetValue("ProxyEnable", 1);
            registry.SetValue("ProxyServer", proxyIP.Text);
        }

        private void navigateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.webBrowser1.Navigate(navBox.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean like this?

`private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try {
            RegistryKey registry = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings", true);

            registry.SetValue("ProxyEnable", 1);
            registry.SetValue("ProxyServer", proxyIP.Text);
            }
            catch
            {
                
            }
        }`

Comment: Nevermind silly me, I just remembered how to catch en exception.

Comment: It didnt throw me an exception, this seems to be one of those sneeky errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing the work on `Form_Load()`, which means it will only run the code when the form is loaded. Any changes made after the form is loaded, will not change the value.

You need to do the work on a different event, such as a button click (i.e. add a save button) or `Form_Close`

Comment: Thank you for explaining that so well! I get tunnel vision when I am dedicated that my answer should be the right one even though in most cases its not, I understand what you mean and how it works, thanks for the great answer!